# How to show my destination by adding the time(24 hour) to the time left?

Tags: python, time, clock, addition

So I have to make a program for class that lets the user input the time (hour and minute part), how many miles are left, and their miles/hour then it has to output the current time 00:00, travel time remaining _ hours and _ minutes left, then what time they will reach destination 00:00

We can only use input, int, round, str, format in our program. So far I have

```
print("Welcome to the travel advisor program.")

hour = int(input("Enter current time, the hours part, using a 24-hour format: "))
num = int(input("Enter current time, the minutes part: "))
minute =format(num, "02d")
miles = int(input("Enter distance to destination in miles: "))
mph = int(input("Enter speed in miles/hour: "))

time_travel_hour = (miles // mph)
time_t = (miles / mph)
travel_time_minute = round((time_t - time_travel_hour) * 60)
clock_format = str(time_travel_hour) + str(":") + str(travel_time_minute)
current = str(hour) + str(":") + str(minute)

print("\n")
print("Here is your trip report")
print("Current time is " + str(current))
print("Distance to destination is " + str(miles) + " miles")
print("Travel speed is " + str(mph) + " miles/hour")
print("Travel time remaining:", time_travel_hour, " hours and", travel_time_minute, "minutes")
```

I tried making adding hour and travel_time hour together and it worked, but when I add num (minute) and travel_time_minute together it just keeps going past 60 so it doesnt go into the hour.

Answer (score 2):

Generally, when solving problems like this it's much easier to think in terms of one unit.   When dealing with time, that single unit is often seconds, but for this case, it can just as easily be minutes.  Once you have the input from the user, if all of the problems you need to solve are done in terms of minutes, the math is straightforward enough.  From there it's just a matter of presentation.  It's easy for a computer to think of "120 minutes", but when displaying it to a user, they would expect to see "2 hours, 0 minutes"

```python
# Replacing the input calls here with direct input so the results are
# easily reproducible, it makes discussion about the problem easier on Stack Overflow

print("Welcome to the travel advisor program.")

hour = 12 # int(input("Enter current time, the hours part, using a 24-hour format: "))
mins = 34 # int(input("Enter current time, the minutes part: "))

miles = 150 # int(input("Enter distance to destination in miles: "))
mph = 60 # int(input("Enter speed in miles/hour: "))

# Time in minutes, this makes some of the calculations easier
travel_time = round(miles / mph * 60)

print("\n")

print("Here is your trip report")
# Show what the user input
print(f"Current time: {hour}:{mins:02d}")
print(f"Distance to destination is {miles} miles")
print(f"Travel speed is {mph} miles/hour")

# Show the travel time.  travel_time is in minutes, but present it to the user
# in terms of hours and minutes
# 'travel_time // 60' divides the current time by 60, and drops the fractional part
# 'travel_time % 60' uses the modulo operator, meaning we return the remainder from the division
print(f"Travel time remaining: {travel_time // 60} hours and {travel_time % 60} minutes")
# Outputs: Travel time remaining: 2 hours and 30 minutes

# And calculate the eta, use the same logic as the travel_time, which
# means thinking in number of minutes since the start of the day
# The '% 24' here lets us "loop" around in case the eta goes beyond the
# 24 hours in a day.  This is just to present the user a valid "wall clock" time,
# and may or may not be desired.
eta = hour * 60 + mins + travel_time
print(f"ETA is {(eta // 60) % 24}:{eta % 60:02d}")
# Outputs: ETA is 15:04
```